# Serielize() jquery não grava as variáveis

Tags: jquery, serialização

Não estou conseguindo gravar as variaveis com o jquery serialize(), esotu fazendo assim, qual seria o problema?

```
//Executa em cada form:
$('.formAjax').on("submit",function() {

    // Pegar o ID do formulário para depois:
    //Captura o elemento que sofreu o evento de "submit"
    const formDetails = $(this);

    var formID=formDetails.data("formid");

    //Remove a palavra quitar_ e deixa somente "debitoX"
 $('.resultado_empresa_selecionada_'+formID).html('<img src="imagens/Rolling-1s-30px.gif">');

$.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "add_email.php",
     data: formDetails.serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
         //Faz alguma coisa

         $('.resultado_empresa_selecionada_'+formID).html(data); 


$('.resultado_empresa_selecionada_'+formID).fadeIn('slow').html(data);

     }
 });
    return false;
});
```

Html

```
<form id="selecionar_empresa_form_273" class="formAjax formAjax2" data-formid="273" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="resultado_empresa_selecionada_273">
<input type="hidden" name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario" value="273">


<select id="atendente" class="form-control atendente" name="atendente" required="">
    <option value="" selected="">Selecine um Atendente</option>
    <option value="vendas@gabcer.com.br">Central de Vendas</option>
    <option value="claudia@gabcer.com.br">Claudia</option>
    <option value="ceia@gabcer.com.br">Céia</option>
    <option value="claudialima@gabcer.com.br">Claudia Lima</option>
    <option value="neide@gabcer.com.br">Neide</option>
    </select>


<button type="submit" class="botao_add">Adicionar atendente</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: o que gera no `formDetails.serialize()`?

Comment: seria gerado as varaiaveis do formmulario

Comment: seria aqui $('.resultado_empresa_selecionada_'+formID).html(data); mas não funciona

Comment: certo mas o que não funciona? `formDetails.serialize()`  retorna alguma coisa, dá erro??

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

Troque

```
formDetails.serialize();
```

por

```
formDetails.toJSON();
```

e trate o controller para receber o arquivo JSON.

Comment: preciso que seja com o serialize(); obrigado pela atenção amigo

Comment: Por nada, estou a disposição!